# Content Security Policy 'self' not working in mobile Safari on iOS 8.2?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, content-security-policy

In our web-app we have CSP set up as report only, however we would one day like to arm it so it blocks potentially malicious content. We appear to be getting erroneous reports from iOS 8.2 (iPad and iPhone) that look like this:

```
 {"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://one.two.example.edu.us/",
 "referrer":"",
 "violated-directive":"font-src 'self' *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com",
 "original-policy":"default-src crwebinvoke: crwebinvokeimmediate: crwebnull: 'self' https://localhost:0/chromecheckurl 'self' localhost:* data: wss://localhost:* ws://localhost:* ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.googleapis.com localhost:*; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com code.jquery.com; font-src 'self' *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com; report-uri /CSP/Report",
 "blocked-uri":"null",
 "source-file":"https://one.two.example.edu.us/bundles/vender-head?v=0dU-czAflklsV7hMNDvsoTAY6f5NVb4pP01dZ_rIvO81",
 "line-number":1}}
```

The document-uri and the source-file are identical. So I cannot understand why iOS 8.2's mobile Safari would claim that this violates font-src 'self' as that is clearly a self hosted document.

The users all appear to be using iOS:

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/41.0.2272.58 Mobile/12D508 Safari/600.1.4
 Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4
```

Has anyone encountered this and or found a work-around? I am worried that if I armed CSP it will start blocking those fonts for iOS users.

Comment: At https://one.two.example.edu.us/bundles/vender-head?v=0dU-czAflklsV7hMNDvsoTAY6f5NVb4pP01dZ_rIvO81 are there any @font-face usages? If so where and how are they being used?